# Bootstrap Responsive Menu Not Closing After Opening

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, responsive

Hi so im kinda new to bootstrap, made shrinking navbar from bootstrap 4.5.3 but the responsive menu not closing after opening it, help will be appreciated thanks.

```
<!-- Start of Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top px-5">
    <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold text-light" href="https://www.google.com.pk/" style="border-radius:15px" style="border:3px">&nbsp;<img src="img/GrowFastMarketinglogov4.png" width="200px" height="50px">&nbsp;</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler hvr-bounce-to-bottom collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            About
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Program</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End of Navbar -->
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `collaspsed` from this line and try to  implement

```
<button class="navbar-toggler hvr-bounce-to-bottom collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

**full code **

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top px-5">
    <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold text-light" href="https://www.google.com.pk/" style="border-radius:15px" style="border:3px">&nbsp;
<img src="img/GrowFastMarketinglogov4.png" width="200px" height="50px">
&nbsp;</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler hvr-bounce-to-bottom " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            About
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Program</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End of Navbar -->
```